# To keep widgets in their place when a new widget is introduced in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I am using Tkinter to make a simple Rock-Paper-Scissors game, and when the score is updated to 1 or when the first point is scored the other widgets are moving by some distance. I tried adding and removing padx values but this doesn't change anything. I am still learning so if I can improve the code, please do suggest me.
Thanks.

```
computer_score=0
score=0
label_score=None
 
def Rock():
    global computer_score,score

    option_list=["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
    rand=rint(0,len(option_list)-1)


    label_check=Label(root,text=("Computer chose "+option_list[rand]),font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"),bg="white")
    label_check.grid(row=4,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)

    if option_list[rand] == button1.cget("text"):

        label_res=Label(root,text="It's a Draw, Try again",font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"),bg="white")
        label_res.grid(row=5,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)
    
   elif option_list[rand] == option_list[1] :
    
       computer_score=computer_score+1
       label_score=Label(root,text=computer_score,font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"),bg="white")
       label_score.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=4)
       label_res=Label(root,text="Computer Won, Try again",font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"),bg="white")
       label_res.grid(row=5,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)

   else:
       score=score+1
       label_score=Label(root,text=score,font=("Helvetica",13,"bold"),bg="white")
       label_score.grid(row=0,column=3)
       label_res=Label(root,text="You won!!, Play again?",font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"),bg="white")
       label_res.grid(row=5,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)
```

A similar code is for paper and scissors too and when the score is 1, the other widgets are moving away. Their code is also kept below.

```
button1=Button(root,text="Rock",command=Rock,height =2, width = 8,font=(8))
button1.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)

button2=Button(root,text="Paper",command=Paper,height =2, width = 8,font=(8))
button2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)

button3=Button(root,text="Scissors",command=Scissors,height =2, width = 8,font=(8))
button3.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)

label1=Label(root,text="Rock Paper Scissors",font=("Comic Sans MS",22,"italic"),bg="white")
label1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W+E,padx=100,pady=(0,5),columnspan=2)
```

Hope you all understood it, sorry for any mistakes, this is my first time asking and I am still learning how to write clean code.
Thank you.

Edit: Actually, I tried to use a method where the result is decided by just comparing the text on button pressed, so to avoid the hassle of big code but I couldn't get any help, so if anyone can think of such, help with it too.
Basic Idea:

if button_text== randint_ list item:
it is draw

as such, I wanted to do instead of above mentioned whole code for Rock. But I donno how to get the text of the button.

Comment: widgets have a display option called place(relx, rely) which you might want to use

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach to this, basically have all the labels pre-paced in the window an then use the `.config()` method on them to change the texts (you can continue with your approach as well). I have predefined the widths of the label, this will prevent them from resizing dynamically as the text in them changes. Here's the modified code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

computer_score=0
score=0
label_score=None
 
def Rock():
    global computer_score,score

    option_list=["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
    rand=random.randint(0,len(option_list)-1)


    label_check.config(text="Computer chose "+option_list[rand])

    if option_list[rand] == button1.cget("text"):

        label_res.config(text="It's a Draw, Try again")
    
    elif option_list[rand] == option_list[1] :
    
        computer_score=computer_score+1
        computer_score_label.config(text=computer_score)
        label_res.config(text="Computer Won, Try again")

    else:
        score=score+1
        player_score_label.config(text=score)
        label_res.config(text="You won!!, Play again?")

root=Tk()

button1=Button(root,text="Rock",command=Rock,height =2, width = 8,font=(8))
button1.grid(row=1,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)

#commented since code was unavailble for this part
'''score_frame=Frame(root)
score_frame.grid(row=0,columnspan=5)
score_frame.pack_propagate(False)

button2=Button(root,text="Paper",command=Paper,height =2, width = 8,font=(8))
button2.grid(row=2,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)

button3=Button(root,text="Scissors",command=Scissors,height =2, width = 8,font=(8))
button3.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)'''

computer_score_label=Label(root,font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"),bg="white",width=3)
computer_score_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
player_score_label=Label(root,font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"),bg="white",width=3)
player_score_label.grid(row=0,column=3)
label_res=Label(root,font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"),bg="white")
label_res.grid(row=5,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)
label_check=Label(root,font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"),bg="white")
label_check.grid(row=4,column=1,pady=5,padx=20,columnspan=2)

label1=Label(root,text="Rock Paper Scissors",font=("Comic Sans MS",22,"italic"),bg="white")
label1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W+E,padx=100,pady=(0,5),columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I changed the code but still, the problem persists, and now the letters r getting glitchy too...and another thing is if we r using config() first, aren't we referencing first before even declaring a label..I got an error becoz of that too. Anyway thanks for ur response.

Comment: I hope you have checked my entire code and not a part of it, because as far as I am aware it has no errors and works fine. I have declared the labels, kindly go through the entire code before making such a claim.